# Adding default webparts to pagelayout in office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365, provisioning

I am trying to add a default webpart to PageLayout

I tried using this

```
<div class="col-3 col-md-3" id="sidebar">
            <WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart webpart="true" runat="server" 
                __WebPartId="{76b0ec97-18db-4d84-9d22-b1fc1476d9e6}"
                Title="Quick Links"
                Description=""
                PartImageLarge="/_layouts/15/images/mscontl.gif"
                PartOrder="0"
                ID="g_d2e2e9c9_5554f_4c66_8ab8_07b5ee9d871d"
                ChromeType="TitleOnly"
                ContentLink="/sites/Name/Style Library/Html/Links.html"
                ></WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart>
            <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="RightSideBar" ID="SideBar"/>
        </div>
```

Now this is present by default when I create pages using this page layout, but there is no delete option for that webpart.

How can I add webpart inside the webpart Zone? I have also exported the content editor webpart as webpart and uploaded it. It would be great if I can add those webparts to the webpart Zone in the PageLayout

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="RightSideBar" ID="SideBar"> 
  <ZoneTemplate>
                 <WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart webpart="true" runat="server" 
                __WebPartId="{76b0ec97-18db-4d84-9d22-b1fc1476d9e6}"
                Title="Quick Links"
                Description=""
                PartImageLarge="/_layouts/15/images/mscontl.gif"
                PartOrder="2"
                ID="g_d2e2e9c9_5554f_4c66_8ab8_07b5ee9d871d"
                ChromeType="TitleOnly"
                ContentLink="/sites/Name/Style Library/Html/Links.html"
                ></WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart>
</ZoneTemplate>
            </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, Webpart should be inside webpart zone. Since in your code you have embbeded your actual webpart code you can't see/edit webpart properties in Edit-page mode.

1. Open you page layout(i.e. layoutname.html).
2. Search for "PlaceHolderMain" and Design your page skeleton with HTML & CSS inside this div.
3. Then insert webpart zone snippet in respective skeleton which you must create using "DesignManager".
4. click save and publish the pagelayout.
5. Create a new Page using this pagelayout.
6. Edit and add what ever webpart you wanted in to respective zone.

> [Reference](http://sharepointcommunity.de/blogs/owirkus/archive/2013/07/15/sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-custom-page-layout.aspx) for detailed step to create pagelayout using designmanager.